# execute mysql_query after data is loaded into the database by jquery to php script

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this php code :

```
$kid = $_GET['document'];
$url = $_GET["url"];
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("repository", $con);
$url =  mysql_real_escape_string($url);
$url = htmlspecialchars($url);
$exists = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM url WHERE url = '$url' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($exists) == 1) {
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM url WHERE url = '$url'" );
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM paragraphs WHERE url = '$url'" );
    }
require("/htmlpurifier-4.3.0-standalone/HTMLPurifier.standalone.php");
require("/htmlpurifier-4.3.0-standalone/HTMLPurifier.autoload.php");
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html($url);
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier();
$body = $html->find('body', 0);
echo $html->find('title', 0);
$cleanbody= $purifier->purify($body);
echo $cleanbody;
echo '<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
echo '<script src="extract.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
$html->clear(); 
unset($html);
```

What happens here is that an html file is loaded, the body is found, purified, and is extracted by "extract.js" (which calls another php script to load it into a database). What I want to happen now is get the url_id (auto incrementing field) of the inserted url and then do a redirect after ALL of this is complete (executing a mysql_query and then a header location redirect, seems to be doing this before anything is loaded into the database). Perhaps running a mysql_query for the url_id where it matches the given url, after some condition satisfies the data has finished loading?

Comment: which url_id are you refering to? And how are you currently doing your redirect ?

Comment: im doing my redirect via header(location:), and im referring to what is the equivalent of mysql_insert_id(), but since that is referenced in the php script called by extract.js, I can't get that result on to this script above

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to understand the server/client principle. You need to remember that the PHP just generates some HTML and sends it to the client. You can't know when the client will request the execution of the other PHP script.

Furthermore, you need to learn more SQL. It doesn't make sense to use a SELECT just to detect if a row exists, and then DELETE it if it does, not using the result at all. You might as well just run the DELETE statement no matter what. If you want to know whether it DELETE'ed anything, use `mysql_affected_rows()`. Also, consider using prepared statements, as it make it easier to protect against SQL injection.

If the extract.js is just extracting some tag from the HTML (without user input), you could do that on the server-side, and you wouldn't have to send it to the client at all.